# PDFs for Olympiad preparation

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, contest-math

Could someone please recommend me some pdf files containing theory for topics that come up often in maths olympiads? I'm currently working through one about inequalities, and I'm really enjoying it. I want to take part in an olympiad this year, but I feel like I definitely need to learn some more theory. I'm looking for anything in Number Theory, Combinatorics and Algebra as well, but Geometry-related material is especially appreciated.

This is the one I'm doing right now, if anyone's interested (45 pages):
https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/161/articles/Riasat_BasicsOlympiadInequalities.pdf

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is the right place to ask this. Perhaps Meta would be better?

Comment: @questionasker I disagree; resource recommendations are welcome enough on the main site to have their own tag. Meta should only be used for questions about the site itself (or the meta site, of course).